# BitTitan (405) Method Not Allowed

Tags: exchange-migration

Trying to migrate mail from on prem exchange server to O365, and getting a 405 method not allowed error.  I've tried some of the things out there to allow all verbs in IIS and disable webDAV, but those didn't seem to work.

Any other thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

First, I undid all of the things I did about verbs.  Seems one of two things may have been the problem.  One, BitTitan just wasn't working that day.  Two, I rolled back the public DNS autodiscover A record back to the on-prem IP address.  If you're having this problem, and you've already changed your public autodiscover record, you might want to try changing it back, and doing that later.  Though, it seems more likely that BitTitan's customer support is just terrible.